# How to negate sets of surrogate pairs?

Tags: javascript, regex, unicode

I've been looking at matching unicode characters outside the 0x0FFFF range using JavaScript surrogate pairs.

[This article](http://inimino.org/~inimino/blog/javascript_cset) shows how to match them, so to match ascii lower case letters OR the mahjong tile red dragon (U+1F004 ) I can use:

```
/[a-z]|\ud83c\udc04/g
```

The surrogate sequence means the collection can't all live in one character class, so how can I negate it? i.e. how can I match any character that isn't in the `[a-z]` range AND isn't the surrogate pair `\ud83c\udc04`?

I want to use this in a replacement operation, in the same way that -

```
'123'.replace(/[^a-z]/g, '' )
```

- would result in an empty string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Allow every other sequence outside the range:

```
/[\u0000-\u0060\u007B-\uD83B\uD83D-\uDBFF\uE000-FFFF]|\uD83C[\uDC00-\uDC03\uDC05-\uDFFF]/g
```

A shorter alternative would be a negative lookahead. They're often avoided due to implementation bugs in IE<8, but should work for this case. But you would have to be careful not to accidentally match the second code unit in the surrogate pair:

```
/(?![a-z\uDC00-\uDFFF]|\uD83C\uDC04)./g
```

Or wait and hope for ECMAScript Sixth Edition to give us astral plane support in RegExp...

Comment: Thanks. I think I'm going to try and avoid doing this altogether though. Trying to negate huge sets like `\p{Ll}` - looks unpleasant in JS.

Comment: @Tim: yes, given that JS (as of ES5) doesn't support the Unicode character classes it's painful. You can use XRegExp Unicode to get that support, but it doesn't have the astral plane characters (or treat surrogates as special) so if you really needed classes for the astral planes it would still be unpleasant.